# IllegalAccessException when using QuerydslPredicateExecutor with JpaRepository

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Application:

- kotlin 1.6
- jdk 17 (also tried 8 and 11)
- gradle 7.3
- spring-boot 2.6.0

  - spring-data-jpa
- querydsl 5.0

  - jpa
  - kotlin
  - apt
  - kotlin-codegen

I'm trying to use the `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` with a `JpaRepository`, but when the application starts, it fails to initialize with an `IllegalStateException` because it can't access some field or method of the generated Q-class.

Using a `JPAQuery` instead of the `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` repository works though.

Any ideas as to what could be the underlying issue would be appreciated.

The Entity

```
@Entity
class Workplace(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null,
    var name: String,
    var description: String,
    var location: String,
)
```

The Repository:

```
@Repository
interface WorkplaceRepository : JpaRepository<Workplace, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Workplace>
```

The Service:

```
@Service
class WorkplaceService(
    private val workplaceRepository: WorkplaceRepository,
) {
    
    fun findAll(searchOpts: SearchOpts): Iterable<Workplace> {
        return workplaceRepository.findAll(searchOpts.toPredicate())
    }
}
```

Fails with the Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not access method or field: class org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils cannot access a member of class <package>.QWorkplace with modifiers "private static final"

    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.handleReflectionException(ReflectionUtils.java:107) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getField(ReflectionUtils.java:657) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.SimpleEntityPathResolver.lambda$createPath$0(SimpleEntityPathResolver.java:74) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.querydsl.SimpleEntityPathResolver.createPath(SimpleEntityPathResolver.java:74) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor.<init>(QuerydslJpaPredicateExecutor.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getRepositoryFragments(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:272) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getRepositoryFragments(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:242) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepositoryComposition(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:434) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 179 common frames omitted
```

However this works:

The Repository:

```
@Repository
interface WorkplaceRepository : JpaRepository<Workplace, Long>
```

The Service

```
@Service
class WorkplaceService(
    private val workplaceRepository: WorkplaceRepository,
    private val entityManager: EntityManager,
) {
  
    fun findAll(searchOpts: SearchOpts): Iterable<Workplace> {
        return JPAQuery<Workplace>(entityManager)
            .from(QWorkplace.workplace)
            .where(searchOpts.toPredicate())
            .fetch()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to the bug which was fixed in https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/3076 but did not land into a release yet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This seems to be it. Do you know anything about when the next version will be released?